# How to force onCreate in my SQLiteOpenHelper to run when I start my application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm writing an application for Android. If I start it up for the first time `onCreate` runs as intended. It won't run again. That's OK, but I want to force it to run. How can I make it do so?

Comment: I'm inserting some records after creation from an xml file. That file won't change while the app is in production but I'm tampering with it right now.

Comment: How about deleting data in tables when you start? I'm saying that since you usually don't delete the tables in `onCreate`, so you will just get an error when trying to create an already existing table.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications, find the app and Clear Data. That will delete the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications, find the app and Clear Data. That will delete the database and cause `onCreate(...)` of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` to be called next time the app is started.

Comment: @AdamArold : Glad to help. I wasn't 100% sure it was what you were looking for which is why I originally posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do it different way. Content of onCreate put into different method. Then call this method from oncreate. And also call this method instead of force call oncreate.

Comment: It is already in a different method. But I will call this once. I want to call onCreate because of development purposes. You misinterpreted my question.

Comment: yep, I now understand what you wanted achieve. I thinked you want force onCreate on every app start. As mentioned Clear data works, also uninstall and install app.

Answer (score 1):

Write the required code in `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`.

`onStart()` will be called everytime your app restarts.
while `onCreate()` will be called only if the android destroys the activity or you force stop it from settings.